# Remove specific characters from highlighted text using AppleScript or Automator

Tags: applescript

I have a question and maybe someone can point me in the right direction.

I would like to be able to copy Text (mostly from "Get Info") and replace all the “.” with a space excluding the “.”before the file extension using AppleScript or Automator. I'd like to use this service when i right click and select the script or automator service.

E.G
Contraband.2012.DVDRip.htif-NYsIC.avi

will turn to

Contraband 2012 DVDRip htif-NYsIC.avi

I've search everywhere on this site and various places but I just cant seem to find what i need. I don’t know where to start writing this script. Is what i described even possible in apple script? I just need to be pointed in the right direction and I'll try and figure the rest out I'm just at a loss right now.

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Run Shell Script action like this:

```
for f; do
  base=${f##*/}
  [[ $base =~ .+\..+ ]] || continue
  noext=${base%.*}
  mv "$f" "${f%/*}/${noext//./ }.${base##*.}"
done
```

Set "Pass input" to "as arguments". `${f##*/}` removes the longest `*/` pattern from the start of `f` and `${f%/*}` removes the shortest `/*` pattern from the end of `f`.

You could also use a Run AppleScript action like this:

```
on run {input}
    repeat with f in input
        set text item delimiters to "."
        tell application "Finder"
            set ti to text items of (get name of (f as alias))
            if number of ti > 2 then
                set AppleScript's text item delimiters to " "
                set name of (f as alias) to (items 1 thru -2 of ti as text) & "." & item -1 of ti
            end if
        end tell
    end repeat
end run
```